# RxJS groupBy not getting values on subscribe

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a very long list in a MongoDB instance consisting of StockPrices with the following properties:

- timestamp
- symbol
- price

I want to group them by symbol. I use an observable to get the list of StockPrices and inject them in the component, which is this:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import {StockPrice} from '../../model';
import {flatMap, groupBy, mergeMap, toArray} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {of, zip} from 'rxjs';

@Component({
    selector: 'compare-chart',
    templateUrl: './compare-chart.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./compare-chart.component.scss']
})
export class CompareChartComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.route.data.pipe(
            flatMap((data: { stockPrices: StockPrice[] }) => data.stockPrices),
            groupBy(stockPrice => stockPrice.symbol),
            mergeMap(group => zip(of(group.key), group.pipe(toArray())))
        ).subscribe(console.log);
    }

}
```

For some reason there is no value emitted and shown in the console, however I do see that the list of StockPrices is retrieved from the server.
I tried all hints from [rxjs.dev](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/groupBy) and [learnrxjs.io](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/groupby.html).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

flatMap expects an observable to be returned, it seems what you want is to do this instead:

```
flatMap((data: { stockPrices: StockPrice[] }) => from(data.stockPrices)),
```

`from` will turn an array into an observable stream that flatMap can operate on so groupBy can do it's thing.

Worth noting, this isn't strictly necesarry, you can just use the map operator and a synchronous groupBy tool from like lodash or soemthing.

groupBy is a kind of complex operator and it's really only needed if you want to group an actual stream, like if you had a live stream of stock prices coming in from a web socket or a poller or something.

Comment: The `from` addition doesn't work either, it still doesn't log anything. I want to use the RxJS groupBy since I very much like the functional approach and chaining operators together.

Comment: you also need to add a `first()` operator before flatMap, or wrap it all in a `switchMap` or soemthing, as "data" is a non completing observable, so toArray will never emit anything, since it's waiting for an upstream completion... however, using the map operator with a synchronous groupBy function is no less functional in approach.  This is just complexity for complexity's sake. the functional approach means that the same parameters coming in always yields the same result coming out, it does not mean using chained rxjs operators.